# how to parse this XML using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<propertyMetrics month="12" year="2013" propertyId="3923837">
  <metric name="siteTotal" uom="kBtu" dataType="numeric">
    <value>409249.0</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="waterUseTotal" uom="kgal" dataType="numeric">
    <value>2434.2</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="totalGHGEmissions" uom="MtCO2e" dataType="numeric">
    <value>28.5</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="greenPowerOnSite" dataType="numeric">
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
  </metric>
</propertyMetrics>
```

What I would like is to key off the "name" attribute and get the "value" and "uom" associated with that name. I'm struggling to figure out a simple way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a non-simple way?

Comment: One does not simply parse XML

Comment: Can you post some code that illustrates your attempts?  Chances are your close but might have a minor issue or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, I'm not sure about that last 'null' value but it gives the basic idea for getting it as a `Dictionary<string, anonymous>`

```
var doc = XElement.Load(fileName);

var data = dox.Descendants("metric")
     .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("name").Value, 
      e => new { uom = e.Attribute("uom").Value, value =(double?) e.Element("Value") });
```

Comment: You probably should poke a `where` statement in there that eliminates the null like so: `Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Element("value").Value))`. That way you ensure that there are no nulls to mess up the `ToDictionary` call.

Comment: This worked, it was giving me an error until I added the where clause. Thanks guys